# SSRS 2008 word export doesn't print to landscape

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, export-to-word

I have a number of SSRS 2008 reports that need to be exported to word in landscape mode.  The reports look great when exported but when you attempt to print (or even preview) the page Word appears to be trying to print the reports in portrait mode thus cutting off all content to that is more then 8.5" from the leftmost side of the page.

I have ensured that the following settings have been made.

1) Report -> Report Properties -> Landscape is set
2) the paper size is 11" wide X 8.5" high.
3) the body properties are smaller than the overall paper size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and it turns out this is in fact [a bug with SSRS 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/b20da762-c01e-4a87-ac7d-87d45e37be69). Microsoft has a fix available.

First, you will need to install [SQL Server 2008 sp1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=66ab3dbb-bf3e-4f46-9559-ccc6a4f9dc19&displaylang=en).

Next, install the [SQL Server 2008 Sp1 Cumulative Update Package 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971491)

I installed both and the Word document exported with the correct print settings.

Answer (score 0):

Set your paper size to the normal 8.5" wide and 11" high. The landscape setting should automatically do the translation of height and width.

Comment: Setting the report to landscape automatically changes the paper size to 11" Wide X 8.5" high.  If I manually change these values back the orientation is reset to portrait.