# Printing in landscape or portrait automatically rotates text, SSRS

Tags: printing, reporting-services, orientation, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

We have a 80mm X 60mm report in SSRS (ver 11.0.2100, embedded in an AX 2012 client) which appears on the screen without problems but when printing directly to a label printer the output is rotated 90º and reduced to fit in the label.  Exporting to PDF seems to be ok, however, and this is not a linked report, [which has another bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455476/ssrs-2008-r2-printing-in-portrait-rather-than-landscape-from-report-server-lin?rq=1).
[image: Horizontal report]

I have tried rotating everything 90º as a test, but the result is the same
[image: Vertical report]

I don't know if this is an issue regarding:

- Parametrization of the SSRS report?
- Problem of printing via remote desktop?
- Problem with the destination device, an EasyCoder PF4i printer.
- Check [print preferences](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/0bbc1d76-6207-4be4-8691-73df9f7efb97).  Especially the "[Always use driver settings](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/15552161-F3EF-4E78-BE7E-8B4595151F48)" or "[Print directly to printer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e6f29862-9893-410d-88b5-905db40b1607)" option.

NOTES:

1. [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889698/ssrs-2005-how-to-print-4-x-3-label-as-portrait-ssrs-assumes-landscape), with some interesting resolutions.
2. [SSRS8 Similar problem when exporting to Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978734/ssrs-2008-word-export-doesnt-print-to-landscape).
3. Will need to also [update my printer driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3762418/15530).
4. Always check SSRS version versus SQL version.

Comment: Did you update SQL? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1469283/4509

Comment: A good comment, Jan.  We still have SQL Server 2012 RTM, and it really needs SP1 installed.  Will chase this up now :)

Comment: Just to update Jan's suggestion, we have reproduced the incident printing from a PDF file (exported from SSRS) on the remote client, so am less confident that it is directly related to Reporting Services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating BOTH the EasyCoder PF4i printer and the EasyCoder PF4i printer driver apparently resolved the issue.